# Searching an array for specfic numbers and printing out all corresponding variables

Tags: java, arrays

```
void searchForPopulationChange()
  {
     int input;
     int searchCount = 0;

     System.out.println ("Enter the Number for Population Change to be found: ");
     input = scan.nextInt();
     boolean found = false;
     for (searchCount = 0; searchCount < populationChange.length; searchCount++)
     {

        if (populationChange[searchCount] == input)
        {
           found = true;
           break;
        }
     }
     if (found)
     {
        System.out.print(""+countyNames[searchCount]+" County / City with a population of "+populationChange[searchCount]+" individuals\n");
     }
     else
     {

        System.out.print("WRONG INPUT");
     }

  }
```

}

hello, above is currently my program.
I am having an issue with having it pull out ALL of the corresponding variables.
IE: I enter "200", there are (2) units in the array that have a corresponding (200) value,
however, this only prints out 1 of them.

Anyone have any quick pointers?

Answer (score 2):

instead of breaking when you find your value

```
 for (searchCount = 0; searchCount < populationChange.length; searchCount++)
 {

    if (populationChange[searchCount] == input)
    {
       found = true;
       break;
    }
 }
 if (found)
 {
    System.out.print(""+countyNames[searchCount]+" County / City with a population of "+populationChange[searchCount]+" individuals\n");
 }
```

just print it on the spot

```
 for (searchCount = 0; searchCount < populationChange.length; searchCount++)
 {

    if (populationChange[searchCount] == input)
    {
       found = true;
       System.out.print(""+countyNames[searchCount]+" County / City with a population of "+populationChange[searchCount]+" individuals\n");
    }
 }
```

you can still check for wrong input after your loop is finished

```
 if (found == false)
 {
    System.out.print("WRONG INPUT");
 }
```

Comment: Doing that makes me move the else statement back into the for loop
and then my output shows the 2 (found) variables,
but then also includes a huge wall of spam of" wrong input " wrong input"

Comment: @user2517185 i've edited my answer.  you can still check the value of `found`

Comment: @user2517185 if you need to repost code, than you can edit your question.